# Problemas con hora de mi datetimepicker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, calendar

Estoy creando un calendario y no quiero que permita seleccionar fechas **pasadas**, en el `js` estoy colocando lo siguiente:

```
<script>
$('.datepicker-default').datetimepicker({
    language:'es',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    startDate: '-0d',
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii',
});
</script>
```

Funciona bien para el día pero para la **hora no**, ya que son las 16:05 horas y no me permite seleccionas las 17 horas sino que se habilita son las 18 horas (Como muestro en la imagen)

[image: DIA]

[image: Hora**texto en negrita**]

Answer (score 0):

[datetimepicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) te ofrece los metodos minDate y minTime

Un ejemplo de esto:

```js
$(function () {

    $("#datepicker").datetimepicker({
        language: 'es',
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii',
        minDate: 0,
        minTime: new Date().getTime()
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```